# Reducing unnecessary same values in Class member variables

Tags: class, memory, optimization, member

```
class A
{
 public int a;
 public int c;
}
```

I will create 10 instances from A.Then I will create 15 instances from A again... go on. first 10 instance will have same value for a variable and next 15 instances will have again same value for a.But I don't mean that both group has same values for a .Problem is create same a value 10 times in first group and 15 times in second group on memory unnecessary.

What would be Best solution or solutions  for reduce unnecessary datas in this situation?

Comment: I dont know that it is related a question to a language .If really it is related  so c# or java can be .

Comment: Yes,it is a little related to language too.In C we can use pointers also for .net we can use pointers.but writing unsafe code doesn't attract me.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `c` are actually just integers, it won't be worth your time trying to optimize them out of the memory space; in most cases, anything you would use to do so would take up more space than the integers themselves.

However, if `a` and `c` are actually objects that take up a significant amount of memory, you could instead put object pointers (or holders, depending on the language) as members of `A` instead of the objects themselves. That way the only memory duplicated in the pointer.

Comment: object pointers mean referance type variable ? If so i gave similiar answer below.But i don't know how much space will take refance members.

Comment: References to an existing object are frequently little more than pointers, and take up a small amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that static member will not work for this problem.Because instance groups will have different values.

this  can be one of the solutions.What can other else ?

```
class Common
{
  public int a;
}
class A
{
  public Common a;
  public int c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a `HashSet<T>` help?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is

```
class A
{
  public int? a;
  public int c;
}
```

but instead of create new instance of int? class we should to assign same instance.But casting int? to int will be ugly to use and cause performance issues.